# WCF equivalent of ServiceDescriptionReflector

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

For an asmx webservice ServiceDescriptionReflector can be used to generate a schema programmatically for message validation.

Is their a WCF equivalent for runtime schema generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the WSDL generation process, implement a Contract or Endpoint behavior and inject a custom [IWsdlExportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) implementation.

Here's an [older sample](http://winterdom.com/2006/09/asampleiwsdlexportextensionforwcf) I wrote on that a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks like the WsdlExporter class is what I'm after.